# Huge latency on REST Api calls iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, alamofire

I've encountered a very strange issue during the development of my app. Naturally we have a lot of REST APIs we're working within the app, but recently I've noticed a bug I cannot explain for more over a week already.

**The problem:**

API responses come with delay (2+ seconds) on iPhone 6.

**Setup**:

xCode 9, Swift 4, Deployment target iOS 9+, Alamofire 4.7

**Testing:**

At first I noticed that my screens that are heavily rely on API responses started to work much slower than usual. When it became visually apparent my first thought was the problem is with the recent Alamofire update. I logged server response time, request completion time and latency. The problem with latency only occurred on iPhone 6.

I decided to make a pure test, so I created a new application with the only purpose to test API response times. I created a simple client with two methods: one using `Alamofire` and the second using `URLSession` to make sure the problem has nothing to do with Alamofire.

*Note: I used two different iPhone 6 with 10 and 11 iOS installed.*

Here's the average latency outputs for physical devices:

```
iPhone 5s iOS 10: 0.655 sec
iPhone 7  iOS 11: 0.572 sec 
iPhone 7+ iOS 11: 0.561 sec
iPhone 6  iOS 10: 2.512 sec
iPhone 6  iOS 11: 2.441 sec
```

Simulator outputs didn't depend on selected model or iOS version, and averaged around 0.5 sec.

There were also no significant differences between using `Alamofire` or `URLSession`.

I tested 2 APIs: one from the project I'm working on, and the second from [openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/api). Both showed latency growth on iPhone 6.

By now I'm lost and have no idea what may cause such lags on iPhone 6, while any other devices tested working as expected. Any ideas on the problem or further test suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a proxy setup ? when you open your API from a browser you get the same delay ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I'm not using proxy

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif it seems like I'm also getting delay, when I open API from a browser on iPhone 6

Comment: try from a computer browser , if the issue persist it mean that the problem is from your end point API

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif the problem only appears on iPhone 6 as I mentioned in the initial question. I opened APIs in desktop browser and also in Postman, it's working as intended.

Comment: I am having the same issues, but with an iPod Touch 6th gen. Same code on other devices are fast, only on the iPod the latency increased to 2+ secs. API response is fast. You got this solved?

Comment: @stephangroen the issue was resolved at the backend side. It had something to do with the balancer (or the cache?) that were addressing wrong instances. Can't tell more on this.